# I have an error in my php insert into code

Tags: php, insert-into

There is an error:

> Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''')' at line 2

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username,"");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) 
{
exit();
}
else
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

$sql="insert into make_master(make_id,make_name)
values($id,$name)";
mysql_select_db('pds', $conn);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) 
{

    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();

}   
}




?>
```

Comment: put a space between your table name and your `(make_id...` part

Answer (score 3):

You should change your code to use the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) interface, it's much more secure!

The reason your query is not working is because you need to quote the values for the SQL query to work:

```
insert into make_master(make_id,make_name) values ('$id','$name')
```

But it's not recommended to it that way, because it will make you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). (Or in other words: You can be easily hacked)

Comment: Quoting numbers is optional.